# Error in Default_web_client_id in Android Studio Google authentication using firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

In Google authentication using firebase in android studio, when I do not set the  default_web_client_id, it throws error to add string value resorces.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmtKr.jpg)

But when I add string value resorces it shows that duplicate string

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykSQP.jpg)

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I want the solution...how to fix it?